# Do Events causing exception how to trace

Tags: windows-phone-7, doevents

I have a code where Application.DoEvents is causing problems and throwing exceptions. When a modal popup is opened and application has to wait for user activity , this code is written to execute in a loop to process background tasks until user's activity . Can someone tell me how can I trace (in debugging) what process is called from DoEvents which causes exception .

Here is some of the code . Can I trace what happens inside DoEvents :

```
private readonly AutoResetEvent Event = new AutoResetEvent(false);

 while (_Event .WaitOne(20, false) == false)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(0);
                }
```

Comment: *Everything* happens inside DoEvents().  Which is why you should never use it.

Comment: Instead of asking how to get `DoEvents` to behave, ask how to achieve whatever it is you're implementing, but without the need for `DoEvents`.